# Update unit column from table1 to table2

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sum

Tables:

```
mysql> select * from table1;
+------+------+------+
| no   | nm   | unit |
+------+------+------+
|    1 | ABC  |   10 |
|    2 | ACX  |   20 |
|    3 | AYU  |   30 |
+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

```
mysql> select * from table2;
+------+------+------+
| no   | nm   | unit |
+------+------+------+
|    1 | ABC  |   40 |
|    2 | ACX  |   20 |
+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Required Output:**

```
mysql> select * from table2;
+------+------+------+
| no   | nm   | unit |
+------+------+------+
|    1 | ABC  |   50 |
|    2 | ACX  |   40 |
|    3 | AYU  |   30 |
+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Of course, this is no longer selecting everything from `table2`, but performing an operation on data from two tables.

Comment: you may want to take a look on grishas answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update `Table2` as required output then you need to update the already exists rows first then insert new rows from `Table1`:

You can update unit using `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE Table2 t2
  JOIN 
       (SELECT nm, SUM(unit) unit
       FROM
       (
           SELECT * FROM Table1 t1
           UNION ALL
           SELECT * FROM Table2 t2
       ) tbl
       GROUP BY nm
       ) tbl1
    ON t2.nm = tbl1.nm
   SET t2.unit = tbl1.unit;
```

Then you can add rows from Table1 which do not exist on Table2 (e.g. `nm=AYU`)

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT t1.`no`, t1.`nm`, t1.`unit`
  FROM Table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.nm = t2.nm
 WHERE t2.nm IS NULL;
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM Table2;
| NO |  NM | UNIT |
|----|-----|------|
|  1 | ABC |   50 |
|  2 | ACX |   40 |
|  3 | AYU |   30 |
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c275f/1)

**Remember** update the table first. Otherwise it will duplicate the units.

Comment: @user2741674 - This should be a different question.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking around and saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7070518/1091386) which I thought was more sensible, that arithmetic should be done outside of the DB manipulation. But if you wish to use SQL for this, I will edit it into this answer later.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to select data from two tables as required output then try this:

```
SELECT MIN(no) NO, nm, SUM(unit) unit
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM Table1 t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM Table2 t2
) tbl
GROUP BY nm;
```

Output:

```
| NO |  NM | UNIT |
|----|-----|------|
|  1 | ABC |   50 |
|  2 | ACX |   40 |
|  3 | AYU |   30 |
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64c8d/10)

Answer (score 0):

select

no,nm sum(unit)

from

(

select * from table1

union all

select * from table2

) as temp  group by no,nm;